# How to loop through the properties of anonymous type in a list

Tags: c#, linq, collections, pivot, anonymous-types

If I have the following LINQ query:

```
 var outstandingDataTotalData = from t1 in dtTotal.AsEnumerable()
                                                  join t2 in dtOutstandingData.AsEnumerable() on
                                                   new
                                                   {
                                                       priv_code = t1["priv_code"],
                                                       pri_ded = t1["pri_ded"].ToString().Trim()
                               
                                                   } equals
                                                     new
                                                     {
                                                         priv_code = t2["priv_code"],
                                                         pri_ded = t2["pri_ded"].ToString().Trim()
               
                                                     }
                                                   into ps
                                                   from t2 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       adjustment_value = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["adjustment_value"].ToString(),
                                                       amount_outstanding = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["amount_outstanding"].ToString(),
                                                       amount_outstanding_priv = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["amount_outstanding_priv"].ToString(),
                                                       amount_outstanding_ded = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["amount_outstanding_ded"].ToString(),
                                                       diff_outstanding = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["diff_outstanding"].ToString(),
                                                       exchange_rate = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["exchange_rate"].ToString(),
                                                       SalYear = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["sal_year"].ToString(),
                                                       SalMonth = t2 == null ? string.Empty : t2["sal_mon"].ToString()
                                                   };
```

---

Now `outstandingDataTotalData` is a list of anonymous type. And I have the following class:

```
 public class AdjustmentTotal
    {
        public string SalYear { get; set; }

        public string SalMonth { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

How to loop through  `outstandingDataTotalData` properties to fill `List<AdjustmentTotal>` as the following example:

If the result set of `outstandingDataTotalData` =

```
[0]{ adjustment_value = "100.00", amount_outstanding = "80.00", amount_outstanding_priv = "60.00", amount_outstanding_ded = "30.52", diff_outstanding = "0.36", exchange_rate = "", SalYear = "2018", SalMonth = "1" }

[1]{ adjustment_value = "1500.00", amount_outstanding = "5040.00", amount_outstanding_priv = "", amount_outstanding_ded = "", diff_outstanding = "0.36", exchange_rate = "", SalYear = "2018", SalMonth = "1" }
```

I want the result set of `List<AdjustmentTotal>` as:

```
2018  1   100.00
2018  1   1500.00
2018  1   80.00
2018  1   5040.00
2018  1   60.00
2018  1   
2018  1   30.52
2018  1   
2018  1   0.36
2018  1   0.36
2018  1
2018  1
```

Comment: have you tried `outstandingDataTotalData .ToList<AdjustmentTotal>();` ?

Comment: @viveknuna the properties are not the same

Comment: List<AdjustmentTotal> totals =  outstandingDataTotalData.Select(x => new AdjustmentTotal() { SalYear = x.SalYear, SalMonth = x.SalMonth,Value = x.adjustment_value}).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng :  `Value` is not always = `adjustment_value`

Comment: Your null checks can be reduced to  `amount_outstanding = t2?["amount_outstanding"].ToString()??""`. If you work with typed datatables it can be further reduced by making the column a string and setting the NullValue to empty, then it doesn't throw on null

Comment: Use same code and set value to whatever it should be.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Nice note

Comment: *Value is not always = adjustment_valu* - in that case make the necessary code adjustment, like `Value = somelogic?s.adjustment_value:s.other_value` etc. I don't think that fact could be discerned from what was posted

Comment: @jdweng: The value of  `Value` may = `adjustment_value or amount_outstanding or amount_outstanding_priv or amount_outstanding_ded or diff_outstanding or exchange_rate` based on the iteration as the example above

Comment: @CaiusJard It's based on the iterations not on a specific logic as the example above.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. I see that there are more items in your list than you claim your query outputs but it's not obvious why. Can you add more explanation?

Comment: Oh. I think I get it; it's like unpivot of N properties into N rows of one property. You should make your life easy; don't pull them out to properties in the first place

Comment: @CaiusJard the SQL query return this result and i want all the values of these properties to listed in one property sorted according to the iterations  as the example

Comment: @CaiusJard exactly  = unpivot , Just I didn't remember the terminology :D

Comment: Suggestion - if you reduce the indentation the code will fit on the screen. Highlight those lines in VS and SHIFT+TAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easy, don't extract to separate properties. Make the extract as an array:

```
select new {
  someArray = new[]{
    t2["adjustment_value"].ToString(),
    t2["amount_outstanding"].ToString(),       
    t2["amount_outstanding_priv"].ToString(),
    t2["amount_outstanding_ded"].ToString(),
    ...
  },
  SalYear = ...,
```

}

So you end up with an object with 3 properties, two strings SalXxx and an array of strings (the other values). The array of strings means you can use the LINQ [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) it to flatten it. You'll see in the msdn example they have owners with lists of pets (variable number of pets but your values are fixed number) and after selectmany it's flattened to a list where the owner repeats and there is one pet. Your lowercases values are the pets, the SalXxx values are the owners

Once you get a working query you can actually integrate it into the first query ..

Sorry for not posting a full example (and I skipped the null checks for clarity) - the code is very hard to work with on a cellphone

---

Edit:

So, you say you want the results in a particular order. Both Select and SelectMany have a version where they will give the index of the item, and we can use that.. because you basically want to have these objects:

```
var obj = new [] { 
        new { SalYear = 2018, SalMonth = 1, C = new[] { "av1", "ao1", "aop1", "aod1" } }, 
        new { SalYear = 2018, SalMonth = 2, C = new[] { "av2", "ao2", "aop2", "aod2" } }
    };
```

Be like `av1, av2, ao1, ao2..` so we want to sort the results first by the index of the inner array, then by the index of the outer array

We use a SelectMany to dig out the inner array and then for every item in the inner array we make a new object that has the data *and* the indexes (of the inner and the outer):

```
obj.SelectMany((theOuter, outerIdx) =>
  theOuter.C.Select((theInner, innerIdx) => 
    new { 
      SalYear = theOuter.SalYear, 
      SalMonth = theOuter.SalMonth, 
      DataItem = theInner, 
      OuterIdx = outerIdx,
      InnerIdx = innerIdx
    }
  )
).OrderBy(newObj => newObj.InnerIdx).ThenBy(newObj => newObj.OuterIdx)
```

You will probably find you don't need the ThenBy; sorting by the InnerIdx will leave a tie (every InnerIdx in my list is represented twice -there are two innerIdx=0 etc) and things in linq sort as far as they can then no futher - because theyre sorted by OuterIdx already (when they went into the query) they should remain sorted by OuterIdx after they tie on InnerIdx.. If that makes sense. Belt and braces!

Comment: There's a little problem here, I want `t2["adjustment_value"]` then `t2["adjustment_value"]` from the second array and after that ` t2["amount_outstanding"]`then `t2["amount_outstanding"]` from the second array and so on. this code solve half of the problem

Comment: What can I say! U are brilliant, just amazing. Thank U so much,I'm really grateful for your magic.

Answer (score 1):

```
outstandingDataTotalData.Select(s => new AdjustmentTotal {
    SalYear = s.SalYear,
    SalMonth = s.SalMonth,
    Value = s.adjustment_value
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a eum :

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            List<AdjustmentTotal> totals = new List<AdjustmentTotal>();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)VALUE.END; i++)
            {
                foreach (var data in outstandingDataTotalData)
                {
                    AdjustmentTotal total = new AdjustmentTotal();
                    totals.Add(total);
                    total.SalMonth = data.SalMonth;
                    total.SalYear = data.SalYear;
                    total._Type = (VALUE)i;
                    switch ((VALUE)i)
                    {
                        case VALUE.adjustment_value :
                            total.Value = data.adjustment_value;
                            break;
                        case VALUE.amount_outstanding:
                            total.Value = data.amount_outstanding;
                            break;
                        case VALUE.amount_outstanding_ded:
                            total.Value = data.mount_outstanding_ded;
                            break;
                        case VALUE.amount_outstanding_priv:
                            total.Value = data.amount_outstanding_priv;
                            break;
                        case VALUE.diff_outstanding:
                            total.Value = data.diff_outstanding;
                            break;
                        case VALUE.exchange_rate:
                            total.Value = data.exchange_rate;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public enum VALUE
    {
        adjustment_value = 0, 
        amount_outstanding = 1, 
        amount_outstanding_priv = 2, 
        amount_outstanding_ded = 3, 
        diff_outstanding = 4, 
        exchange_rate = 5,
        END = 6
    }    
    public class AdjustmentTotal
    {
        public string SalYear { get; set; }

        public string SalMonth { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public VALUE _Type { get; set; }
    }
```